# listview into collapsible set doesn't refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery mobile Project with some pages into main, one of them has this structure:

```
    @*Pagina componentes del documento*@
    <div id="PagDocumentoComponentes" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a id="BtnVolverPagComponentes" href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Volver</a>
            <span id="PagDocumentoComponentesAdvertencia" style="color:red">Kit Incompleto</span>
            <h3 id="PagDocumentoComponentesTitulo">Componentes del Kit</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>
                <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="ComponentesDocumentoDisponibles">
                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e">
                        <h2>No hay componentes</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Collapsible set marked with id="ComponentesDocumentoDisponibles", is filled dynamically with this code:

```
function mostrarComponentes(tcLink) {

$.post(tcLink, function (dataComponentes) {
    $('#ComponentesDocumentoDisponibles').children('.ui-collapsible').children('ul').remove('li',false);
    $('#ComponentesDocumentoDisponibles').children('.ui-collapsible').remove();
    //  Se recorre cada item del kit que tiene componentes variables
}).error(function (dataError) {
    alert('No se pudo caragr la información el kit (' + dataError + ')');
}).success(function (dataComponentes) {

    var kitNode = ''
    var ItemNode = '';
    $(dataComponentes).each(function (object) {
        var kit = $(this)[0];
        var idComponente = kit.id;
        kitNode += format('<div data-role="collapsible" data-max="1" id ="{0}" data-theme="e">', idComponente + "Collapsible");
        kitNode += format('   <h2>{0}</h2>', kit.StrDescripcion);
        kitNode += format('   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="{0}">', idComponente);
        //  Se recorre cada item que compone el kit  
        $(kit.ItemsEnKit).each(function (object) {

            var item = $(this)[0];
            var iconoResta = '<image src="' + item.Image.toString() + '" class="ui-li-icon" style="width:22px;height:22px" />'

            ItemNode = format('<li data-cantidad="{0}" data-icon="plus" id="{1}">', item.NumCantidadAsignada.toString().trim(), item.Id);
            ItemNode += format('    <a href="#" onclick="modificarComponentes({0},{1});">{2} {3}</a>', quote(item.AccionDisminuir), quote(item.IdCantidad), iconoResta, item.StrDescripcion);
            ItemNode += format('    <a href="#" onclick="modificarComponentes({0},{1});"></a>', quote(item.AccionAumentar), quote(item.IdCantidad));
            ItemNode += format('    <span id="{0}" class="ui-li-count">{1}</span>', item.IdCantidad, item.NumCantidadAsignada);
            ItemNode += format('</li>');
            kitNode  += ItemNode;
        });
        kitNode += format('   </ul>');
        kitNode += format('</div>');
    });
    $('#ComponentesDocumentoDisponibles').html(kitNode);
    $('#ComponentesDocumentoDisponibles').collapsible();
    $('#ComponentesDocumentoDisponibles').find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
    $(dataComponentes).each(function (object) {
        var kit = $(this)[0];
        $("#" + kit.id  + "Collapsible" ).collapsible();
        try
        {
            $("#" + kit.id).listview();
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });
});
//PagDocumentoComponentes
//ComponentesDocumentoDisponibles
}
```

in a typical case this function must build a two Collapsible ítems with a listview into each one.

My problem is in the try catch block, some times it Works fine, but another times it throw this exception:

```
Unable to get the property 'jQuery182044178615987382985' not defined or null reference
```

When try to initialize each list.

The collapsible elements allways initialize fine,

NOTE: If I visit the parent page of collapsible set at least one time, all things go fine.

Comment: try refrshing collapsible only without calling `listview()`. When you enhance parent element, all children get enhanced. So try `.collapsible();` or `.collapsible().trigger('create');` after doing all changes/appending items.

Comment: Tks, allready tried that, but in this case, my listviews appear as a normal html links.

Comment: `$('[data-role=collapsible-set]').collapsibleset().trigger('create');` as it's a collapsible set.

Comment: Tks again. I'm going to try it

Comment: Tks a lot , it fixes the listview appearance but it throw the same exception. This thing is driving me crazy

Comment: Remove any other method of enhancement and place at the end of your function, after appending all items. Are you using another library other than jquery?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37743/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-omar)

Comment: Have you reached a solution?

Comment: NO.... I'm still figthing with this

Comment: @Omar Finally solved. Just moved my code from **success** event to **done** event of jquery **post** object.

Comment: @Omar Gracias, me tomo bastante entenderlo. pero bien. Mucho para aprender de Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a fix: All proccess of my data was performed on `success` event of jQuery `post`, just move it to `done` event.

It seems a problem of synchro between my app and jQuery times.